The formula doesn't affect all required cells in Google Sheets
I created a formula in Google Sheets designed to return one of the three versions of a referenced cell based on criteria in a range of other cells. It works with just the two COUNTIF, but not with the third added to them, which is what I want:
=if(COUNTIF($D2:$H2,"▢"),$N2&CHAR(827)&" 
",if(COUNTIF($D2:$H2,"⭘"),$N2&CHAR(778),
if(COUNTIFS($D2:$H2,"⭘",$D2:$H2,"▢")$N2&CHAR(778)&CHAR(827)&" ",$N2)))



You may try:
=let(x,countif($D2:$H2,"⭘") ,y,countif($D2:$H2,"▢"), a,char(778), b,char(827), c,$N2,
 if(and(x,y),c&a&b,
 if(x,c&a,
 if(y,c&b,c))))

